# Who moves faster; Crash or Coco?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

In Crash Bandicoot N-Sane Trilogy, you can play as either Crash, or Coco. Each moves slightly differently, in particular when swinging across overhead bars.

Crash moves slower, but with longer swings, and Coco moves faster, but with apparently shorter swings.

So does one move across these bars faster than the other or not? And if so, is there any other places where their speeds differ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Playing as Crash vs Coco is purely a cosmetic difference. While the animations differ, the actual moves and movement are the same.

From [this list of version differences](https://www.crashmania.net/en/games/crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy/changes/):

> Coco is now fully playable in all three games. She controls just like Crash, but she has her own unique animations.

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/191634-crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy/75530683):

> Are there any gameplay differences between the 2 or is it purely cosmetic?
>
> Cosmetic.
>
> Sadly, yes, it is cosmetic only. Do you want to play as a male or a female?

And from [this thread asking the same question as this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/crashbandicoot/comments/6kx1fs/is_it_just_me_or_is_coco_faster_on_the_monkey_bars/):

> Is it just me or is Coco faster on the Monkey bars?
>
> Her animation has more motion in it, but the actual physics engine movement speed is identical. It's a minor optical illusion.

Comment: Brilliant :) I wasn't entirely sure that they would have gone to all that effort to recreate the physics engine for a new character, but like your quote states, the "optical illusion" is what got me